# Expiration is not working in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

I have configured expiration settings in DocuSign like below(Envelopes to be expired in one day). But I am not getting any warning emails and envelope also not getting expired. Do I need to do any other configurations?

[image]

Comment: First, send an envelope through the web interface and see if the behavior is as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few items in play here - if you are sending these envelopes through the REST API, please check the documentation regarding the notification block (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm?Highlight=expiration)

There are 3 ways to set envelope expiration:

1. If you set useAccountDefaults=true when creating the envelope w/the API, then it will use the account level configuration you have in your screenshot.
2. If you do not specify useAccountDefaults, then it will use a DocuSign cloud generic default of 120 days.
3. You can also explicitly specify the expiration value on a per envelope basis in the expirations section of the notification block.

Comment: There's more up to date information on this page: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/default-api-reminder-and-expiration-settings